# jQuery Autocomplete Select Label and Value and show only label

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to search customer data with jQuery autocomplete. I have following scenario.

Customer name and mobile number should be display as list selection and on selection, I have to display only customer name to autocomplete textbox.

I have tried following code, but it won't work.

```
$("#txtServiceCustSearch").autocomplete(
           {           
              source: function (request, response) {
                  $.ajax({
                      url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/AutoComplete.asmx/GetServiceCustomer") %>',
                      data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                      dataType: "json",
                      type: "POST",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      success: function (data) {
                          $("[id*='grvHistory']").empty();
                          response($.map(data.d, function (item) {                             
                              return {
                                  label: item.split('$')[0],
                                  val: item.split('$')[1],
                                  val1: item.split('$')[2],
                                  val2: item.split('$')[3],
                                  val3: item.split('$')[4],
                                  val4: item.split('$')[5],
                                  val5: item.split('$')[6],
                                  val6: item.split('$')[7],
                                  val7: item.split('$')[8]
                              }
                          }))
                      },
                      error: function (response) {
                          alert(response.responseText);
                      },
                      failure: function (response) {
                          alert(response.responseText);
                      }
                  });
              },
              select: function (e, i) {
                  $("#txtServiceAddress").val(i.item.val);
                  $("#txtPinCode").val(i.item.val1);
                  $("#txtServiceContactNo").val(i.item.val2);
                  $("#txtLandmark").val(i.item.val3);
                  $("#txtEmailID").val(i.item.val4);
                  $("#txtServiceDOB").val(i.item.val5);
                  $("#txtServiceMobileNo").val(i.item.val6);
               $("#txtServiceCustSearch").val(i.item.val7); },
              close: function (e, i) {
              },
              minLength: 3
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
 e.preventDefault()
```

in select: function (e, i)